# Multiple case statements in Impala

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, impala

I have one table with transaction_date,sal,name and age columns.

Query: If transactions is made in last 24 months. If this is Yes, then it should check the age whether age lies in between 18-54 or not. If this condition is yes it should display a string as success, failure on false condition. If the transactions is made in last 24 months. If this is false, then get the no. of transactions. If it is Yes, then average of salaries

I have given overview as below according to my requirement. This to be executed in impala as a query.

transaction made in last 24 months --Yes->Is Age in between 18-54 --Yes->success
                                                                  --No-->failure

```
                                --No-->get no.of transactions--Yes-->sal avg
```

Please share me the exact query in impala for the same

Comment: Please post the query you written or tried to write.

Comment: How would you define in last 24 months? Does this need to be strict?